# Elasticsearch - Search with in near realtime (1 sec)

Tags: elasticsearch

I come across the following phrase  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/documents-indices.html

When a document is stored, it is indexed and fully searchable in near real-time—​within 1 second.

Assuming the 1 sec is subjective and depends on various factors , can we safely assume it is atleast 1 sec ? And also, I see different time intervals that will kickin as part of the indexing like refresh interval, etc , is this 1 sec is approximately sum of all those intervals (intermediate )

Howmuch realtime it is when we say elasticsearch is (near) realtime search engine

Comment: not 'at least', in most cases it is much shorter than 1 sec

Comment: The 1 sec interval might depend on various factors like network latency , shards etc ..? right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default refresh interval (controlled by the index setting `index.refresh_interval`) is one second. The sentence you cite means exactly that. By default, a document you index will be available for search within **at most** one second, but it can be less than that.

If a refresh happens at instant T and you index a document at that same moment, then the underlying segments will be refreshed in pretty much exactly one second and your document will be searchable after that refresh.

If a refresh happens at instant T, and you index your document 500ms after that instant, then it will be available for search just 500ms after being indexed.

That also means your document could be available just a few milliseconds (say 10ms) after being indexed if you index it at instant T+990ms after the last refresh that happened at instant T.

It's not exact science, so that one second should be taken with a grain of salt, sometimes it could last a tad longer, say 10xx ms, where xx depends on various factors. You should not rely on that duration being nano-exact, though.

So **near-real time** simply means the duration of that refresh interval (which you can modify).

Comment: "It's not exact science, so that one second should be taken with a grain of salt, sometimes it could last a tad longer, say 10xx ms, where xx depends on various factors. You should not rely on that duration being nano-exact, though." . The 1 sec interval might depend on various factors like network latency , shards etc ..? right ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, network latency between nodes themselves, the segment merge process might be busy finalizing another operation, there might be resource contentions due to other heavy searches/writes, etc. But in normal operations, that 1 second is pretty steady.